# stat64 a large (~5GB) file

Tags: c, raspbian, stat

On raspbian, I am trying to do `stat/stat64` a large file: `5.4G /tmp/some.mpg`. Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define __USE_LARGEFILE64
#define _LARGEFILE_SOURCE
#define _LARGEFILE64_SOURCE
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main(){
    char filename[] = "/tmp/some.mpg";
    struct stat64 myst;
    int x = stat64(filename, &myst );
    if ( x < 0 ){
        printf("x is %d\n", x);
        perror("stat failure");
    }
    printf("%s size: %ld\n", filename, myst.st_size);

    return 0;
}
```

It it however displaying erroneous info when I run it:

```
$ gcc bigsize.c -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -o bigsize
$ ./bigsize 
/tmp/some.mpg size: 1435916040
$ ls -ltr /tmp/some.mpg 
-rw-r--r-- 1 XXX YYYY 5730883336 Jul 27 08:44 /tmp/some.mpg
```

On `x86_64` this seems to work OK, not on `armv7l`

Please show me the right way to accomplish this, thanks!

**Update 1**

this seems to work, after changing printf from `ld` to `llu`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define __USE_LARGEFILE64
#define _LARGEFILE_SOURCE
#define _LARGEFILE64_SOURCE
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main(){
        char filename[] = "/tmp/some.mpg";
        struct stat64 myst;
        int x = stat64(filename, &myst );
        if ( x < 0 ){
                printf("x is %d\n", x);
                perror("stat failure");
        }
        printf("%s size: %llu\n", filename, myst.st_size);

        return 0;
}
```

**Update 2**

This works, after reading up the answers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

#define __USE_LARGEFILE64
#define _LARGEFILE_SOURCE
#define _LARGEFILE64_SOURCE
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main(){
    char filename[] = "/tmp/some.mpg";
    struct stat64 myst;
    int x = stat64(filename, &myst );
    if ( x < 0 ){
        printf("x is %d\n", x);
        perror("stat failure");
    }
    printf("%s size: %llu\n", filename, myst.st_size);
    printf("%s size: %jd\n", filename, (intmax_t)myst.st_size);
    printf("file %s is %" PRIdMAX " bytes.\n", filename, (intmax_t)myst.st_size);

    return 0;
}
```

Compiled thusly:

```
$ gcc bigsize.c  -o bigsize -Wall -Wextra ; echo $?
0
```

Run:

```
 $ ./bigsize 
/tmp/some.mpg size: 5730883336
/tmp/some.mpg size: 5730883336
file /tmp/some.mpg is 5730883336 bytes.
```

Thanks to all!

Comment: Where are your error checks? How do you know the `stat64()` call was successful?

Comment: `off_t` on that system is possibly not defined as a `long`, but as some larger type. Do you get any warnings about that `printf()` when you compile with warnings turned on like you always should be doing? (`-Wall -Wextra` is a good starting set)

Comment: thanks! `bigsize.c:15:21: warning: format ‘%ld’ expects argument of type ‘long int’, but argument 3 has type ‘__off64_t {aka long long int}’ [-Wformat=]
  printf("%s size: %ld\n", filename, myst.st_size);` - your reply helped immensely! :)

Comment: Feel free to [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) or @Shawn step in and add an anwser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is you telling `printf()` that you're giving it an argument that's a `long`, but then actually passing it an argument that is in this case a `long long`, causing undefined behavior when the two types are different sizes. It works on the x86_64 system because `long` and `long long` are both 64-bit, but I bet the arm system uses 32-bit `long`s and 64-bit `long long`s.

One portable approach when you don't know the exact type to print out is to cast it to the largest possible one (`intmax_t` from `<stdint.h>`, and use the print macros from `<inttypes.h>` to display it:

```
printf("file %s is %" PRIdMAX " bytes.\n", filename, (intmax_t)myst.st_size);
```

Comment: ``bigsize.c: In function ‘main’:
bigsize.c:18:24: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘PRIdMAX’
  printf("file %s is %" PRIdMAX " bytes.\n", filename, (intmax_t)myst.st_size);
                        ^~~~~~~``

Comment: `PRIdMAX` is useless and difficult to read. `%jd` does the exact same thing.

Answer (score 2):

1. Enable all compiler warnings - they help faster than posting a question on Stack overflow.
2. When printing an integer type like `myst.st_size`, which is type `off_t`, that lacks a matching `printf` specifier, consider simply casting to the widest type and using its matching printf specifier.

   ```
   // printf("%s size: %ld\n", filename, myst.st_size);
   printf("%s size: %jd\n", filename, (intmax_t) myst.st_size);
   ```